# Boot ubuntu from usb installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04, dell, nvme

I am trying to install ubuntu from usb. After choosing a space boot (/boot) i can't find it in the list "device for boot loader installation"

Comment: The ESP (EFI System Partition) and `/boot` are different things; with the ESP being a directory only on the `/boot/efi` file-system, ie. ESP and the `/boot` partition are expected to be different partitions; are you mixing those two things up.

Comment: Actually, it s my first time trying to work on Ubuntu. I don't know much. The (/boot) i meant is the boot space for ubuntu. And my issue is that i have created that space but i can't find it in the "device for boot loader installation" list, where i need to select it first than clicking on the install button

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, because you are manually partitioning the disk you are making a dual boot partition.

## Preparing the instalation

For installing Ubuntu from a USB Live, you first need to make the USB Bootable. As it seems you have already taken this step, let me guide you with the instalation.

## Installing Ubuntu

### Booting from Live USB

I am going to assume you are installing 22.04.3 LTS (there is no much difference if you are installing another version so this should work anyway)

**In your computer, make sure that you have "USB Boot" or "Live Boot" enabled**

Once you have done that, you can either make the **Live Boot** the **primary boot option** in your BIOS, or you can search for the Fn Key that your computer manufacturer has stablished to **select which partition to boot**. In my case I have a DELL laptop, and the Fn key set for accesing the Boot menu is F12, so I have just to click several times F12 on startup for the Boot menu to appear. If your computer is from another manufacturer, look for the Fn key of that manufacturer.

> If you chose to make Live Boot the primary option in BIOS, it will automatically Boot from the Ubuntu Live USB (in case it's plugged obviously)

> If you chose to select the Boot option from the Boot Menu of your computer, use the arrows to select the partition you want to launch the computer from (it usually has the name of the USB manufacturer). It will then Boot from Ubuntu Live USB

Regardless of the way you make it to run your Live USB, let's continue the instalation:

### Instalation of Ubuntu

Once you have Booted your device with the Live USB, some options will appear. In most of the cases, you want to press enter in the one at the top (the one highlighted). If you don't press enter or any key, this option will be selected by default after a bunch of seconds.

> Ubuntu loading screen appears

When it finishes loading, you will see the background of the distro you have chose and a windows asking you wether you want to try Ubuntu first or you want to install it directly.

**Choose your preferred language for the instalation and click on "Install Ubuntu"**

> Now, what you are displayed may change depending on the distro you are at, you probably will have to choose your keyboard layout and then select the type of instalation you want.

##### Normal Instalation (In case of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

It will install a bunch of apps that is what many users want to have to start

##### Minimal Instalation (In case of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

It will install just a web browser and minimal utilities.

---

Then, you will have other options, like installing additional software and downloading Ubuntu updates while installing Ubuntu

#### Partitioning the disk

> And here comes the "difficult" part

##### Single Boot

> If you want to just have Ubuntu on the computer you are installing, select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"

##### Dual Boot

> If you are making a Dual Boot, click the options which says something like "Install along "xSO" (xSO = another operative system that you have in your computer).

**Note that, if you don't have the partition where you want to install Ubuntu made or you don't have unallocated space in your disk, you might have to go back and resize the disk to create a partition (from the Disks app if you click on "Try Ubuntu" or from the other operative system you have on your machine**

##### More than 2 boots

> **3 or more boots in the same machine**: In this case you probably want to take things manually, click on "Something else". Now in case you made a partition, you need unallocated space, click the partition and press the **-** button to make it unallocated. Now, select the unallocated space at your disk and press **+**. You will now get a pop up to select the filesystem and the space you want to allocate and the direction to mount it. Select "/".

Once you do that, select the new partition and click on "Install Now"

---

> Once you have selected the partitioning way, a new popup will appear to confirm the changes to the disk, click "Continue"

#### Last steps

Finally you will be asked for other things, like timezone, your computer name, username and password.

**Click on Continue**

Now the instalation will begin to write the changes on your disk, once it's finished, restart your computer and it's all done :D

> **Important** Now you may see the grub at startup to select where you want to Boot from, if you don't see it, something probably went wrong.

If this happens you can try to boot Ubuntu from the Boot Menu or reinstall it.

**Welcome to Ubuntu and to the Ubuntu forum!!**

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. I have done all the steps, but after creating the new space for ubuntu (for dual boot) including (/boot, swap and the drive to use for ubuntu) i can't find the boot space (i have already created) in the list "device for boot loader installation"